# AboutMe Link in SharePoint 2013(On Premises)

Tags: user-profile-service

We have a SharePoint site running on SharePoint 2013 on premises. It got "mysite" set up already. from the main site, I am unable to see the about me link to navigate to "MySite". I can see the about me link from the Central Administration site. Also, I can not suit link bar for the main site. I have checked the following.

User Profile service sysnchronisation is running correctly
Service account is having full rights access for SQL Server.

Please let me know how do I display the "About Me" link in the main site.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Service Application Associations for the Web Application in Central Administration. The User Profile Service Application proxy group identifies the connection.